# delete mutiple rows with duplicate values

Tags: sql-server-2005

i have  an table  like this  with columns  and values now i neeed  to get the  output

like this

```
ID  DEPID  Address   Name 
1    1      abc      ram,kumar
1    1      abc      ram,kumar
2    2      abc      vinay
3    2      xyz..    kiran,kumar
4    6      xyz..    anu
5    9      xyz..    pavithra
6    9      xyz..    pavithra,anitha
6    9      xyz..    pavithra,anitha
6    9      xyz..    pavithra,anitha
7    9      xyz..    manu,vachan
7    9      xyz..    manu,vachan
7    9      xyz..    manu,vachan
```

now  i need  output like this

```
ID  DEPID  Address   Name 
1    1      abc      ram,kumar
2    2      abc      vinay
3    2      xyz..    kiran,kumar
4    6      xyz..    anu
5    9      xyz..    pavithra
6    9      xyz..    pavithra,anitha
7    9      xyz..    manu,vachan
```

pls  help me  how  to get the  Query  for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the DISTINCT for this.

```
SELECT ID,DEPID,Address, DISTINCT Name FROM ...
```

Probably something like this.

Comment: You are right, he should use the DISTINCT clause, but the syntax is like this: SELECT DISTINCT Id, DEPID, Address, Name FROM Table

Answer (score 0):

From the look of it your data seems soo wrong....

but this will give u the output

```
select distinct * from <tablename>
```

my 2 cents...

If you are trying to denote some kind of aggregate value through multiple entries of the exact same data, it can be avoided by adding an additional column(say count)..it will not only save space on ur database but also save u the trouble of writing complex sql statements.